# DoesNotExist at / AllocationDetail matching query does not exist

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-views

I know there are a number of questions already on stack overflow related to this issue and I have read them all, but still I am having no success with this issue. I am hoping somebody can help me out with this.

C:\Users\Ravokid\Desktop\E-Fund_2\users\views.py, line 73, in home

```
'money_per_ward' : get_money_per_ward(),
```

C:\Users\Ravokid\Desktop\E-Fund_2\accounting\views.py, line 17, in get_money_per_ward

```
obj = accounting_models.AllocationDetail.objects.all().get(financial_year__start_date=datetime.date.today().year, financial_year__end_date=datetime.date.today().year+1)
```

Comment: Could you share financial_year model? What is the start_date, is it DateTimeField?
If yes you should use ORM like that `obj = accounting_models.AllocationDetail.objects.all().get(financial_year__start_date__year=datetime.date.today().year, financial_year__end_date__year=datetime.date.today().year+1) 
`

Comment: django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Unsupported lookup 'year' for IntegerField or join on the field not permitted.